# Remove all the values from JSON object with null value Using jsonpath

Tags: json, jsonpath, jolt

I have a JSON file from which I need to remove node objects which contain a data value of null. Can this be done?

In the sample JSON below, I need to remove the object where all the  tag has a null value.

```json
{
   "store" : {
      "book" : [
         {
            "category" : "reference",
            "author" : "Nigel Rees",
            "title" : "Sayings of the Century",
            "price" : 8.95
         },
         {
            "category" : "fiction",
            "author" : "Evelyn Waugh",
            "title" : "Sword of Honour",
            "price" : 12.99
         },
         {
            "category" : "fiction",
            "author" : null,
            "title" : "Moby Dick",
            "isbn" : "0-553-21311-3",
            "price" : 8.99
         },
         {
            "category" : "fiction",
            "author" : null,
            "title" : "The Lord of the Rings",
            "isbn" : "0-395-19395-8",
            "price" : 22.99
         }
      ],
      "bicycle" : {
         "color" : null,
         "price" : null
      }
   },
   "expensive" : 10
}
```

We tried using JOLT :

```json
[
  // Flatten an array of photo objects into a prefixed
  //  soup of properties.  
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": "=recursivelySquashNulls"
    }
  }
]
```

But this is resulting in removing Null values but also it is not removing empty json fields

Output which we are getting

```json
{
  "store": {
    "book": [
      {
        "category": "reference",
        "author": "Nigel Rees",
        "title": "Sayings of the Century",
        "price": 8.95
      },
      {
        "category": "fiction",
        "author": "Evelyn Waugh",
        "title": "Sword of Honour",
        "price": 12.99
      },
      {
        "category": "fiction",
        "title": "Moby Dick",
        "isbn": "0-553-21311-3",
        "price": 8.99
      },
      {
        "category": "fiction",
        "title": "The Lord of the Rings",
        "isbn": "0-395-19395-8",
        "price": 22.99
      }
    ],
    "bicycle": {}
  },
  "expensive": 10
}
```

and expected Output is

```json
{
  "store": {
    "book": [
      {
        "category": "reference",
        "author": "Nigel Rees",
        "title": "Sayings of the Century",
        "price": 8.95
      },
      {
        "category": "fiction",
        "author": "Evelyn Waugh",
        "title": "Sword of Honour",
        "price": 12.99
      },
      {
        "category": "fiction",
        "title": "Moby Dick",
        "isbn": "0-553-21311-3",
        "price": 8.99
      },
      {
        "category": "fiction",
        "title": "The Lord of the Rings",
        "isbn": "0-395-19395-8",
        "price": 22.99
      }
    ]
  },
  "expensive": 10
}
```

Any Suggestions How we can do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You rather can use the following spec instead of using `recursivelySquashNulls` by interchanging key-value pairs through use of **`"$": "...@(0)"`** pattern

```json
[
  {
   // convert price values to strings in order to keep the decimal part of them during the interchange operation
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "store": {
        "book": {
          "*": {
            "price": "=toString"
          }
        },
        "*": {
          "price": "=toString"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
   // interchange key-value pairs to get rid of the both values null and null object -> { }
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "store": {
        "book": {
          "*": {
            "*": {
              "$": "&4.&3.&2.@(0)"
            }
          }
        },
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "$": "&3.&2.@(0)"
          }
        }
      },
      "*": {
        "$": "@(0)"
      }
    }
  },
  {
   // switch to the original
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "store": {
        "book": {
          "*": {
            "*": {
              "$": "&4.&3[&2].@(0)"
            }
          }
        },
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "$": "&3.&2.@(0)"
          }
        }
      },
      "*": {
        "$": "@(0)"
      }
    }
  },
  {
   // preserve the decimal value as they are
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "store": {
        "book": {
          "*": {
            "price": "=toDouble"
          }
        },
        "*": {
          "price": "=toDouble"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]

Comment: okay this worked , but we have a scenario where our json keeps on changing , in that scenario this will not work right ? , Is there any generic solution which we can imply for all our json structure

Comment: And also if bicycle value comes , in this case it is still not printing the entire bicycle json field

Comment: @SahilSethi you're completely right, so I've edited to fix; btw, I don't think, even believe there could be a generic way through use of Jolt